# Can you split a NSString into an NSArray of strings based on a content size?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Basically i want to pass an NSString and a CGSize (the content size) and get an NSArray of NSStrings that will fit into this content size.

So for instance i have `@"something really long"` and specify a size `CGSizeMake(20, 10)`, i would get back a `NSArray` of `[@"something", @" really", @" long"]` for example.

Anyone have any ideas / sample code?

Comment: So you want to split on words, and then look for series of those words that fit inside a rectangle? Obviously you'd need to specify font and size.

Comment: Are you interested in solutions for both OS X and iOS?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure this is that straight forward. Is the `CGSize` enough? Does not the amount of text that can fit inside a contentSize depend on the `fontSize` too? Not sure you would want to do all this. It can get pretty complex. Dont see the need for all that.

Instead define some comfortable `contentSize` for your `UILabel` & truncate the rest or even better opt for `Adjust to Fit` along with defining a min. font size. With this iOS will try its best to fit your text keeping in mind the min font size. Here's how to do it in IB -

[image]

Comment: Yes, i assume you would have to do some calculations using the 'sizeWithFont' method. I think i'm looking for an algorithm approach or any sample code if there is any really.

Comment: I agree, if the text is rendered the font size needs to be taken into account.

Comment: This is probably the best answer, an algorithm would be pretty complex and this is a simple solution.

Comment: But the use case of this is that i want to basically create a paged scroll view of labels, so need to break it up into arrays. make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to break by words (break where there is a space) here is a psuedo-code algorithm:

```
1) Get Width as parameter
2) Declare String temp, int breakPoint, array list
3) For Each (character in String)
       Add character to temp String
       if (character is space)
           set breakPoint to currentIndexInTemp    
       end if
       if (temp String size > Width OR character is newline)
           declare String newString
           set newString equal to substring of temp(from 0 to breakPoint)
           add newString to list
           set temp to substring of temp(from breakPoint + 1 to end)
           reset breakPoint
       end if
   end For Each
4) if (length of temp > 0)
       add temp to list
   end if
5) return list
```

I'm sorry if that's terrible pseudo-code, I don't write pseudo-code often (actually, at all) and I'm not familiar enough with Objective-C to write it in the language.

**NOTE**

- The `breakPoint` is the last occurrence of a space, or break in
  characters, if the length is too long then you want to cut at the
  `breakPoint` to prevent chopping words. This is the index in the
  `temp` String only, not the String you're breaking up.

There may be a simpler way to to do this in Objective-C, I don't know, this algorithm is based off a function I wrote in Java to break a string into 80 character lines.

**EDIT**
Added New Line testing. In my example, if it's a new line then break it there whether it's too long or not. Also, when you break the String into an array (the second if) you'll want to reset the `breakPoint` variable. I'd also agree that for overly large portions of text this will add overhead, I've not had issues with text-processing of several hundred characters. Although that was done on a desktop/laptop program.

Comment: I'm not sure this will take into account newlines? I also had a similar implementation, but does not work. Plus the runtime would be pretty slow.

Comment: Text processing runs pretty quick, of course I've never developed for a mobile device but they're getting pretty fast. And adding in a test for a new line is simple.